# Launching Leap Motion Home App is not working in macOS

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, leap-motion, macos-big-sur

I installed Leap Motion controller on macOS Catalina. The installation set up run successfully. However, when I try opening the Home APP it does not appear.

I later upgraded mac from macOS Catalina to macOS Big Sur, but Leap Motion Home APP is still not appearing/opening.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the Home App does not appear is that it is deprecated and no longer being supported on any platforms.

[Reply from Developer on the Forum](https://d2beseu6pw5d2t.cloudfront.net/t/leap-motion-apps-not-working-with-mac-catalina-os/8462)

[Leap Motion Blogpost about the Home App](https://blog.leapmotion.com/app-store-sunset/)

---

That said, you can still develop apps for the Leap Motion on Big Sur using the V2 SDK. If you want to explore pre-built apps, you can take a look at the Apps Gallery and use the Advanced Search to find apps that run on the V2 SDK.

[Leap Motion Gallery of Apps](https://gallery.leapmotion.com/)

[Using the Advance Search for V2 Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzORr.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Leap Motion not working with MacOS Monterey or M1 MacOS Ventura**

Download the latest **Leap_Motion_SDK_Mac_2.3.1** version [here](https://developer.leapmotion.com/releases/mac-2-3-1) or download it directly [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PzO9UPA7dDYQUiSMlxpXNjmQ0CNNdClr/view?usp=sharing).

Once the software is installed you should see it in your top status menu showing like this:

[image]

Using terminal run the following commands:

Check if UVCAssistant is running:

```
> ps -aex | grep UVCAssistant
```

Stop the UVCAssistant process:

```
> killall -9 UVCAssistant
```

*You might have to execute the command multiple times until the Leap Motion Sensor connects and the light turns green or orange*

[image]

If the terminal command doesn't work (M1 macOS Ventura) you can use the following: Open **Activity Monitor** App > Select **Network** Tab > Search for **UVCAssistant** > Select Stop *(Keep stopping until the Leap Motion Sensor connects)*

**Bonus:** If you would like to use it with the **BetterTouchTool** you can download the **btt1.921b.zip** version that supports Leap Motion for MacOSX [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gfehtxu7Afk7HyxPrWvcbt0KAGW4D4lv/view?usp=sharing) *(Direct link to my personal Google Drive)*

The solution is reference [here](https://forums.leapmotion.com/t/leap-motion-controller-macos-monterey-supported-soon/16961/32)